# Diff between Pooled and Cluster Tables?

Tags: sap-data-dictionary

What is the difference between Pooled and Cluster Tables?

Where exactly we use Pooled and Cluster tables ?

How to find Pooled and Cluster Tables ?

Answer (score 1):

Please. A rapid search with google (sap pooled table) gives the exact answer you're searching for on [scn](http://scn.sap.com/thread/780525)

**To summarize :** 
Pooled Table : Pooled tables are logical tables that must be assigned to a table pool when they are defined. Pooled tables are used to store control data.  Several pooled tables can be cominied in a table pool. The data of these pooled tables are then sorted in a common table in the database.

Cluster Table :  Cluster tables are logical tables that must be assigned to a table cluster when they are defined. Cluster tables can be used to strore control data.  They can also be used to store temporary data or texts, such as documentation.

Table pool can contain 10 to 1000 small pool table which has 10 to 100 records. But cluster table can contain very big but few (1 to 10)  cluster table.